# Ajax file upload not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to upload csv file in laravel 5.6 using ajax request. But, the file could not be uploaded. It's showing, the file is required again and again.

## form

```
                    <form class="form-horizontal file-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input required="" type="file" name="import_file" id="import_file" />
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="upload_csv" disabled="true" type="submit">Import CSV or Excel File</button>
                    </form>
```

## AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($('this')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
                url: "{{url('admin/voter/sub/storecsv')}}",
                data: formData,
                type: 'post',
                async: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(response){
                    // console.log(response);
                    alert('uploaded');
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

## Controller

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'import_file' => 'required',
]);
```

It shows that this import file is required. I have gone through many of other similar posts on stackoverflow and many other member seems to achieved success with the same code. But, I couldn't find what I have missed. Any help, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var formData = new FormData($('this')[0]);
```

to this:

```
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
```